# Linker script using to different location counters

Tags: embedded

I'm building an embedded app to simulate a mips32 processor. I have my code which starts at 0xBFC00000 and exceptions/interrupts which start at 0x80000000. Is there a way to incorporate both of these addresses into one linker script file? Thanks!

Comment: Yes there will be, but how you do it will depend on the toolchain used?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. I'm using the gnu tool chain to build my app with the mips x-compiler and the LD linker.